# Updating vim 7.3.429 to 7.3.885 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vim

I have installed version 7.3.429 of `vim` on my Ubuntu 12.04 and want to update to the version 7.3.885. Could someone guide me? I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use this ppa:

https://launchpad.net/~nmi/+archive/vim-snapshots

or compile it from source.

For information on using a ppa see:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

and

https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html